# Filter list not reappearing after empty view shown

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview, android-listfragment

For some reason after being shown an empty view for no matching items, my list view won't reappear after removing all text from the search view.

> Within my adapter class, AFAIK `.clear()` in `mData.clear();` needs to change to something else but I don't know what to.

**ItemListAdapter class**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<Victoria> mData;
    private List<Victoria> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<Victoria> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position).getItem();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getItem());
        holder.description.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getItemDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    /**
     * Filter for filtering list items
     */
    /**
     * <p>An array filter constrains the content of the array adapter with
     * a prefix. Each item that does not start with the supplied prefix
     * is removed from the list.</p>
     */
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = mData;
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<Victoria> resultList = new ArrayList<Victoria>();
                for (Victoria str : mData) {
                    if (str.getItemDescription().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Runs on ui thread
         * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
         * @param results the results to display
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                //Make list invisible
                //Make text view visible
                mFilteredData.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<Victoria>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Before filtering**
[image]

**After filtering with an invalid character**
[image]

**After clearing search view and trying to show list again**
[image]

Comment: Can you please change the logic by replacing "mData.clear();" to "mFilteredData.clear();" in publishResults() method?

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy just done that

Comment: have you tested. Is it working?

Comment: @RaghuRamiReddy No, it still doesn't show the list again. Can you use my code and post your suggested code as an answer please? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple small fixes should get things working right for you.  First, `mData` and `mFilteredData` data should be two different instances at all times. In the constructor, have `mFilteredData` be a new instance copied from `mData`

```
mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
```

Additionally in the `Filter`, you'll need to update the corresponding code to the follow:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
    results.count = mData.size();
    results.values = new ArrayList(mData);
}
```

Then your `getView()` method should be pulling from `mFilteredData` instead of `mData`. Ideally though, the `getView()` method should be using the `getItem(position)` method to access the data.  That way, if you change implementation details of where the data is accessed from, you don't have to remember to update the `getView()` method separately.

Finally as a side note, your filtering code works only because the adapter does not mutate `mFilteredData` or `mData`. Normally, one must heavily `synchronize` the filtering process and other parts of the adapter because `performFiltering()` occurs on a background thread.  If you plan on adding support for modifying the adapter's data after constructing...then you'll need to start adding `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: Could you have a look at the updated code and provide a code suggestion for my class please?

Comment: Your `getView()` is still not pulling from `mFilteredData`

Comment: Just saw one more place where `mFilteredData` instance becomes the same as `mData`.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the array that contains the original data, and when de `Adapter` recreates the list, the array has no data.

The correct thing to do this is to create a copy of the original array, and return the copy as the result every time the list is filtered, leaving the original data untouched. A very good example can be found in the `ArrayAdapter` implementation. See the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#449).

I'll include a copy of the source code here just in case:

```
/**
 * <p>An array filter constrains the content of the array adapter with
 * a prefix. Each item that does not start with the supplied prefix
 * is removed from the list.</p>
 */
private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (mOriginalValues == null) {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<T>(mObjects);
            }
        }
        if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<T> list;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                list = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
            }
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        } else {
            String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
            ArrayList<T> values;
            synchronized (mLock) {
                values = new ArrayList<T>(mOriginalValues);
            }
            final int count = values.size();
            final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final T value = values.get(i);
                final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                    newValues.add(value);
                } else {
                    final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                    final int wordCount = words.length;
                    // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
                    for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                        if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }
        return results;
    }
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        mObjects = (List<T>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note, the `ArrayAdapter` implementation of `ArrayFilter` is quite buggy and I suggest not using it.  http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/

Comment: I see. I've never had that issue because I generally don't change de Adapter data within the same Activity.